# Using accept() and select() at the same time?

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming

I've got an event-driven network server program.  This program accepts connections from other processes on other hosts.  There may be many short-lived connections from different ports on the same remote IP.

Currently, I've got a `while(1)` loop which calls `accept()` and then spawns a thread to process the new connection.  Each connection is closed after the message is read.  On the remote end, the connection is closed after a message is sent.

I want to eliminate the overhead of setting up and tearing down connections by caching the open socket FDs.  On the sender side, this is easy - I just don't close the connections, and keep them around.

On the receiver side, it's a bit harder.  I know I can store the FD returned by `accept()` in a structure and listen for messages across all such sockets using `poll()` or `select()`, but I want to simultaneously both listen for new connections via `accept()` **and** listen on all the cached connections.

If I use two threads, one on `poll()` and one on `accept()`, then when the `accept()` call returns (a new connection is opened), I have to wake up the other thread waiting on the old set of connections.  I know I can do this with a signal and `pselect()`, but this whole mess seems like way too much work for something so simple.

Is there a call or superior methodology that will let me simultaneously handle new connections being opened and data being sent on old connections?

Comment: how about using the IOCP mechanism provided originally on Windows but also available to some extent on other platform: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports     Unix - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794535/linux-and-i-o-completion-ports

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Last time I checked, you could just `listen` on a socket and then `select` or `poll` to see if a connection came in. If so, `accept` it; it will not block (but you <strike>may want to</strike> *really should* set O_NONBLOCK just to be sure)

Comment: Hmm, that's a well-known race condition - the `accept(2)` will block if client drops connection attempt between two syscalls. You *need* the listening socket to be non-blocking.

Comment: This is correct - you can add your listening file descriptor to the `readfds` in your `select()` call, and `select()` will tell you the file descriptor is "readable" if it has a connection ready to `accept()`.  @Nikolai is correct too - the listening socket should be nonblocking and the `accept()` call prepared to handle `EAGAIN`.

Answer (score 7):

you could use listen then use select or poll then accept

```c
if (listen(socket_fd, Number_connection) < 0 )
{
    perror("listen");
    return 1;
}
fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;
int rv;
FD_ZERO(&set); /* clear the set */
FD_SET(socket_fd, &set); /* add our file descriptor to the set */

timeout.tv_sec = 20;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

rv = select(socket_fd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if (rv == -1)
{
    perror("select"); /* an error occurred */
    return 1;
}
else if (rv == 0)
{
    printf("timeout occurred (20 second) \n"); /* a timeout occurred */
    return 1;
}
else
{
    client_socket_fd = accept (socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &client_name, &client_name_len);
}
```

Comment: What if the fd_set also has fds on which data might be coming to read, and not listening?

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a listener in separate process(thread) not to mess things up. And run a worker process on another to handle existing sockets. There's no need for non-blocking listener really. And no thread overhead running 2 threads.

It should work like that: you accept on your listener thread till it returns you a descriptor of client socket and pass it to worker which is doing all dirty read/write job on it.

If you want to listen several ports and don't want to hold one process per listener I suggest you set your socket in O_NONBLOCK and do someth like:

```cs
// loop through listeners here and poll'em for read
// when read is successful call accept, get descriptor,
// pass it to worker and continue listen
while(1){
    foreach( serverSocket in ServerSockets ){
         if( serverSocket.Poll( 10, SelectRead ) ){
              clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
              // pass to worker here and release
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's spinning you've got there; no good.  And one thread per socket is way too many threads.

Comment: what's so bad about this spinning? :) it won't eat any CPU, besides it allows you to listen many ports in one thread.

Comment: This is bad, you're busywaiting with a 10usec timeout on each listening socket one at a time, this WILL eat CPU. It'd be better to use `select` on all the listening sockets at the same time, which will block until at least one has a incoming connection, AND then try to `accept` from each of them (making sure, obviously that each is marked `O_NONBLOCK` and being prepared for `accept` to return `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` for those sockets without a connection).