# Check if basic_socket_acceptor is ready to accept

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm writing a simple single threaded TCP server using [Networking TS](http://wg21.link/n4711). In order to accept incoming connections, I create `std::experimental::net::ip::tcp::acceptor` and call `accept` member function. But it blocks if there is no connection to accept and I don't want that. How can I check if acceptor is ready to accept?

Comment: I am not used to play with experimental features, but in good old socket API, one can use select to know whether a listening socket has a pending connection. The experimental C++ API has probably a method for that.

Comment: I'm guessing the APIs you're using are based on [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html)?  If so I'd expect there to be an [asynchronous version of `accept`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html) as well.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: @G.M. But wouldn't that need a separate thread to wait for new connection? I want to keep stuff as simple as possible and use only one thread.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The underlying implementation more than likely makes use of the `select` system call (as hinted at by @SergeBallesta).  Can you provide more information about exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.  Or, better still, provide a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: @G.M. I'm just writing a hello world server that will do some work while waiting for incoming connections. Basically, calling `DoStuff()` and imaginary `can_accept()` in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if there would be a function that would ultimately call `select`, it would expose a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444729/using-accept-and-select-at-the-same-time). The correct way is to set acceptor to be non-blocking.

```
std::experimental::net::io_context context;
std::experimental::net::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor{context,
    std::experimental::net::ip::tcp::endpoint{
    std::experimental::net::ip::tcp::v4(), 1234}};
acceptor.non_blocking(true);
std::error_code error;
while (true)
{
    auto socket = acceptor.accept(error);
    if (!error)
    {
        // Handle incoming connection
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```