# Does AIO (Linux Asynchronous I/O) equivalent exist in Windows OS (not .NET Framework Level)?

Tags: .net, c, windows, linux, frameworks

I know .NET just introduced Async, but in Linux it is implemented at OS level, does Windows OS has equivalent or is it just simulated on .NET Framework level ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has several asynchronous I/O APIs. Overlapped I/O can be pretty much considered an extension of the regular I/O functions. And for high performance/scalability purposes, there's I/O Completion Ports.

(.NET's async has little to do with async I/O specifically. It's a language-level construct for doing *anything* asynchronously)

Comment: OK thanks would it be possible to bind .NET's async to async I/O ?

Comment: I haven't really looked closely into .NET's async features, so no clue. You might want to ask that as a separate question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows has something called [Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is used for asynchronous I/O.

Quote:

> I/O completion ports provide an efficient threading model for processing multiple asynchronous I/O requests on a multiprocessor system.

It's not tied to any specific development framework.

Also have a look at [Synchronous and Asynchronous I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
.

Comment: funny same question but the other way round for linux :)

Comment: @user310291 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794607/2732969 on ["Linux and I/O completion ports?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2794535/2732969) .