# How to choose thread pool size?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Suppose I have to read, process and update a lot of files in Java. I am going to use one computer with 16 cores. Since I have both IO-bound (read and update files) and CPU-bound (processing) tasks I allocate 2 thread pools.

I would allocate one pool for CPU-bound tasks with 16 threads (the number of threads == the number of CPUs). Now I wonder what the IO-bound pool size is. 
Thread pools of what sizes would you suggest ?

Comment: I would suggest testing. Can't beat actual results you know.

Comment: I'd say the number of processing cores available...

Comment: I would suggest to leave at least 1 CPU for the operating system, then do testing with available tools to check where the bottle-neck in an real-world aproximation

Comment: I never would count on Java about management of threads, for low-level management, you may need to switch to something more reliable, like pthread.

Answer (score 4):

It would depend on your storage capabilities and what kinds of IO you are trying to do. For example, long sequential writes on harddisks would favor a single IO thread, but you would want to scale this according to your requirements.

In this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821025/2855891, BlackAura explains why experimentation and profiling is probably the only way you can really find out.

There are probably already very good articles on this topic.