# How does async work in .NET Core on linux not having IO Completion Ports?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, .net-core, task-parallel-library, io-completion-ports

As far as I understand, Linux does not have [IO Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
That's probably the reason why in Scala (JVM) developer should [explicitly notify](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#blocking) API about blocking operations.

However, Task Parallel Library seems to not bother the developer with such details. Everything works out of the box.

But how then is thread starvation avoided in case of Mono/NetCore on Linux?

Comment: Note that there are other techniques in Linux to make asynchronous operations.

Comment: @xanatos To my shame I am not experienced in OS design and architecture and know near to nothing about Linux internals, hence is the question =)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794535/linux-and-i-o-completion-ports