# How to implement Proactor pattern in python?

Tags: python, concurrency

Is it even possible to make "true" [Proactor style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proactor_pattern) I/O handling implementations possible in Python?

Specifically, I know that Windows has this notion of [I/O Completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) that can spawn threads in the background to handle any asynchronous callbacks from sockets for example. I couldn't find similar API for Linux and any Python wrappers for that.

Comment: Why it would not be possible, did you find an issue while developing it? Please, share an example of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @LouisLac, I've updated the question - I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794535/linux-and-i-o-completion-ports) post answers your question? Do you really need such low-level access to I/O? There are many asynchronous libraries for Python which can make concurrent requests such as AsyncIO + AIOHTTP.